# how to receive 16-bit PCM audio through bluetooth for FFT

Tags: java, android, audio, bluetooth, pcm

I am trying to send audio through bluetooth in android, when receiving data in the server I expect to see 16-bit numbers representing the audio data but I received strange symbols. I can not detect where is the problem. I need to perform FFT on the server side.

```
    int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

   AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            44100,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            minBufferSize);

    while(recording){
        int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
        //convert from short to byte 
        byte[] data = ShortToByte_Twiddle_Method(audioData);
        //send through bluetooth
        blue.write(data);
    }
```

Receiver code:

```
    do {

       bytes = input.read(buffer);
       //writing data to a file
       fil.write(buffer, 0, bytes); 

       } while (true);
```

received data:[image]

why do i see null values in received data?

Comment: Looks like what I would expect for raw `byte`s. Are you expecting a decimal representation of the numbers? If so, you will need to convert the `byte` s to `int` s before writing the file.

Comment: I need to perform FFT on the samples on the server, can i apply FFT directly to raw data or do I need to convert them to decimals?

Comment: That would depend on your FFT implementation, but I suspect you will need to convert. Take a look at `ByteArrayInputStream` and `DataInputStream`.

Comment: Looking at audio data in ascii is nonsense. You need to use a hex display that you can preferably group in by 2-byte words and then you'd see something more meaningful

Comment: It's possible that 8 kHz audio is upsampled to 16 kHz. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco%28%29) states that: The following restrictions apply on input streams: the format must be mono, the sampling must be 8kHz